# Array using a post and a session variable

Tags: php, session

Hello guys I am trying to insert a post_variable into an array and send it with a session variable to a different file, my code for adding the post variable is below:

```
 $sit = array();
    $sit[]=  $_POST['sit'];
    $_SESSION['sit'] = $sit;
```

when I transfer the variable to a different file(customerform.php), I am trying to echo one of the strings into the array using the code below:

```
session_start();

cart =_SESSION['sit'];
is_null($_SESSION['sit'])

;

echo $cart[1];
```

I tried many things but it keeps displaying the following error on my screen:

> "Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\theater\customerform.php on
>   line 9"

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are attempting to access $cart[1], when $cart[1] doesn't exist.

When you add an item to an array without specifying an index, the default beginning index is 0.

So, to access your value, you'll want to use $cart[0];

If you add a second item to your array in the same manner that you did before ($sit[]=  $_POST['sit']), it will be placed at $cart[1] unless you specify a different index.

I also realized that you haven't properly set your value here:

> cart =_SESSION['sit'];

It should be:

```
$cart = $_SESSION['sit'];
```